# Using Sprockets in a non-Rails/Rack project — Getting error on rake compile command

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sprockets

I'm trying to utilize Sprockets on a non-Rails/Rack project and I came across a [how-to guide by Simone Carletti](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/09/using-sprockets-without-a-railsrack-project/)

I have my project setup like so:

```
.
Gemfile
Rakefile
/src
    /javascripts
    /stylesheets
        960.css
```

Gemfile:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem 'sass'
gem 'sprockets'
```

Rakefile:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
require 'pathname'
require 'logger'
require 'fileutils'

Bundler.require

ROOT        = Pathname(File.dirname(__FILE__))
LOGGER      = Logger.new(STDOUT)
BUNDLES     = %w( all.css all.js )
BUILD_DIR   = ROOT.join("build")
SOURCE_DIR  = ROOT.join("src")

task :compile => :cleanup do
  sprockets = Sprockets::Environment.new(ROOT) do |env|
    env.logger = LOGGER
  end

  sprockets.append_path(SOURCE_DIR.join('javascripts').to_s)
  sprockets.append_path(SOURCE_DIR.join('stylesheets').to_s)

  BUNDLES.each do |bundle|
    assets = sprockets.find_asset(bundle)
    prefix, basename = assets.pathname.to_s.split('/')[-2..-1]
    FileUtils.mkpath BUILD_DIR.join(prefix)

    assets.write_to(BUILD_DIR.join(prefix, basename))
    assets.to_a.each do |asset|
      # strip filename.css.foo.bar.css multiple extensions
      realname = asset.pathname.basename.to_s.split(".")[0..1].join(".")
      asset.write_to(BUILD_DIR.join(prefix, realname))
    end
  end
end
```

I run

```
bundle install
```

and the bundle installs successfully.

When I run

```
rake compile
```

I get the following error

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'cleanup'

Tasks: TOP => compile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any ideas on why this might be occurring? Using ruby 1.9.3p194 if that helps debug this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
task :compile => :cleanup do
```

It means the task `:compile` requires `:cleanup` but you have no `:cleanup` task defined. Change it to

```
task :compile do
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Simone. After that, I'm getting this error: `rake aborted! undefined method pathname for nil:NilClass Tasks: TOP => compile (See full trace by running task with --trace)`

Comment: The script doesn't find the bundle. `assets = sprockets.find_asset(bundle)` returns nil. Check the `BUNDLES` constant and make sure the files exist.

Comment: Ah, that did it. I didn't have all.js or all.css created. Thanks! One question though: The build directory is getting created but nothing is being minified, screen.css.scss isn't being compiled, and using `*= require_self *= require_tree .` doesn't seem to combine anything into all.css. It's just taking my js and css files from /src and moving them into /build. Any ideas?

Comment: `assets.write_to(BUILD_DIR.join(prefix, basename))` should write them.

Comment: How would you specify minifiers in this format? I get this error `NoMethodError: undefined method `compress' for :uglify:Symbol`